# Configure Material theme with kendo ui core

Tags: kendo-ui

Can you please let me know, the order in which styles sheet must be referenced for material theme with kendo ui core.

I have referenced styles in the below  order, but the ui doesn’t render like in the kendo demo.

Kendo.common-material.min.css
Kendo.material.min.css

created a `plnkr` for debugging:

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/N9mpRyEyOBjsh22k?open=lib%2Fscript.js%2Fedit%2FN9mpRyEyOBjsh22k%3Fopen%3Dlib%2Fscript.js&preview
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is correct, however, you are loading the LESS-based Material theme. I suspect you are referring to [this TextBox demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/textbox/index?autoRun=true&theme=material-main) that uses the SASS-based theme. Load the [SASS-based theme](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/sass-themes) to get the look of the demo:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.material-main.min.css" />
> ```

[Updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jLQyMTFCWvDrCjpd?open=lib%2Fscript.js%2Fedit%2FN9mpRyEyOBjsh22k%3Fopen%3Dlib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: Yes , I was referring to that text box demo (https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/textbox/index?autoRun=true&theme=material-main)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I didn’t notice that there were two themes: less and sass.

Comment: Looks like only less theme is included in kendo ui core(https://www.npmjs.com/package/kendo-ui-core).